# DIV auto scroll

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a div that has a large number of items in it. I select these items dynamically by clicking a button, overflow is auto in my case. What I want is that when an item that is not visible is selected to scroll the div so that can be visible. How can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Element.scrollTop) property of HTMLElement to set the amount its content is scrolled by.

And you can get the amount you need to scroll by from [offsetTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Element.offsetTop) of the element to which you want to scroll.

For example with this HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <p id="item-1">foo</p>
  <p id="item-2">bar</p>
  <p id="item-3">baz</p>
</div>
```

You could use this JavaScript to scroll the container div to third paragraph:

```
document.getElementById("container").scrollTop = document.getElementById("item-3").offsetTop;
```

Comment: There is a typo on js

    document.getElementById("container").scrollTop

Answer (score 5):

Yet another option is to use **[jQuery](http://www.jquery.com)** along with the plugin **[ScrollTo](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo)**.

Answer (score 3):

When your button clicked and an item selected call this selected item's focus() method. this will cause auto scroll to your element :

```
<div style="height:80px; overflow:auto;">
    <input type="text" id="id1"><br><br>
    <input type="text" id="id2"><br><br>
    <input type="text" id="id3"><br><br>
    <input type="text" id="id4"><br><br>
    <input type="text" id="id5"><br><br>
    <input type="text" id="id6"><br><br>
</div>
<input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id6').focus();">
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for regular "div" elements (at least, not in Safari 4 or Firefox 3).

Comment: The code you've written there works perfectly. However, if you replace the "input" elements with "div" elements, focusing the div element doesn't seem to scroll to it. See http://cloud.quintusquill.com/dropbox/ScrollTest.html for an example.

Comment: yes, I understand now, you're right. I thought he was mentioning form elements, In this case I think it's good to use JQuery plugin. thanks !

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the DIV's scrollTop or scrollLeft property (depending on if the scroll is horizontal or vertical).

I've done this before and used a setTimeout event to make it scroll fluidly, rather than in 1 motion.  This is without JQuery tho.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another option... anchors.

Assign each item a unique ID, and when you want to scroll to a particular item, execute the following JavaScript code:

```
location.hash = itemID;
```

...where `itemID` is a variable that contains the ID of the element you want to scroll to.

Steve