# Javascript question: Detecting children currently in view within an 'overflow: auto;' parent element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, view

See title.  Additionally, how can I tell if a given child element is only partially or else wholly out of view (that is, not within the currently scrolled portion) of my 'overflow: auto;' parent element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/810492/div-auto-scroll) for scrolling to elements in the page, which is related.  Would using some maths with .scrollTop and .offsetTop allow me to do something like what I'm looking for?

Edit: Apparently yes.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard way to detect if an element is fully, partially, or not in view within an overflow element. If you have a simple layout - you can do the math yourself using the Prototype Position APIs: http://www.prototypejs.org/api/position

Take a look at the 'within' method which may work for you: http://www.prototypejs.org/api/position/within

Comment: Says it's depreciated, though.